# Is it possible to modify the emacs buffer with read-only text?

Tags: buffers, read-only-mode

I am new to emacs lisp and emacs itself, coming from vim. I have seen such a nice feature in the idea:

[image: Screenshot]

This is a mutable buffer with read-only text hints: type of a variable and a argument name in the `print` function. I'd like to implement such functionality in the `emacs` editor. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome. Which language is this for?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Hi! this is for the rust language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I think you're asking how you might make certain parts of a buffer read-only.

You can do that by putting text-property `read-only` on the text you want to be read-only.  See the Elisp manual, node [Special Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html). See also node [Changing Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html).

The very simple way of inserting new read-only text is demonstrated in the next example. You can try this example in the `*scratch*` buffer.

```el
 (insert (propertize "some text" 'read-only t))
```

After you inserted the read-only text it is important to know how to remove read-only text. You can ignore the read-only status of buffer text by setting the special variable `inhibit-read-only` to a non-nil value.

Mark the read only text `some text` in our example and type the following stuff:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))`

Note that the key sequence <kbd>M-:</kbd> runs the command `eval-expression` and the expression is input in the mini-buffer.

It is also possible to set the `read-only` text property for an already existing buffer-substring. That is demonstrated in the following example which produces the same read-only text as the former example.

```el
(progn
  (let ((pos1 (point)))
    (insert "some text")
    (put-text-property pos1 (point) 'read-only t)))
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to use it: how to add a text into some place of a buffer and mark it with `read-only` special property? I have found the documentation but only for these properties but not about a function which sets it.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time. When I check it and it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Could you also tell me please, how can I make its background color different from other text and how can I make so that cursor is unable to be on the text but only before or after it?

Comment: That's 3 questions. But the answer is to look at the Elisp manual, node [Changing Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html). You can get there inside Emacs using `C-h i`, choosing Elisp manual, then `i text property TAB` (or in this case just `g changing p TAB`. See node [Special Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html) for a description of properties `read-only` and `face`.

Comment: The code in my answer shows how to insert `some text` at position `pos1` and make that text read-only. Define a function that uses that code, if you want. Put it on some hook, if you want. Make it a command, if you want. All of those things are possible (and different questions).

Comment: I did not say that your answer is bad and that it did not answer something. It was an additional question and I just thought as it related to original question, it would be good to ask it here. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Seems really important to also mention [text property stickiness](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sticky-Properties.html), and that you should disable the default stickiness by adding the read-only property to the `rear-nonsticky` property so that your read-only property doesn't start contaminating text inserted right after the read-only text.